# Handedness in Quaternion multiplication

Tags: quaternions, wolfram-alpha

I've received some code (which I didn't write) and decided at some point to write test cases for the Quaternion math implementation.

I used Wolfram alpha to get the result q1 * q2, where:

q1 = (4.0 + 1.0i + 2.0j + 3.0k)

q2 = (8.0 - 5.0i + 6.0j - 7.0k)

Wolfram alpha calculates the result to be (46 - 44i + 32j + 12k)

My code calculates the result to be (46 + 20i + 48j - 20k)

This is not equal to Wolfram Alpha's calculation of q1 * q2 (which meant my test failed), but interestingly, it's equal to q2 * q1.

Similarly, q2 * q1 calculated by my code is equal to Wolfram Alpha's result of q1 * q2

Normally I would think that my multiplication function is performed incorrectly, but the function is used several times in the program with correct results.

I was wondering if this is considered a bug, or just a design choice. Is this quaternion multiplication performed in a "left-handed" manner, compared to the norm, which uses right handed math? I do know that handedness matters for rotation matrices, but I haven't read anything about Quaternions. Is there another explanation for this?

Comment: I've only used Wolfram Alpha (the website) as a calculator to get the correct result of the calculation and nothing more. My code uses C# and not Mathematica. I intended this to be only a math-related question. I could move it to StackOverflow if it still does not make sense for this stack exchange

Comment: Ah, I actually understand your question a little better now. No, keep it here. I'll delete my original comment.

Comment: Sounds like someone wrote the multiply function with composition of rotations in mind.  `mult(q1,q2) = q2*q1` is a "natural" choice when you want to say `q1` is the first rotation and `q2` the second, but for all other cases, I'd say that's pretty counter-intuitive.

Comment: @Muphrid This is actually probably the best explanation. The quaternion code is indeed used for rotations. Now it's making sense. Can you please post that as an answer and flesh it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your multiplication function is actually trying to give the net quaternion for a composition of rotations.  That is, you have a function `mult(q1, q2)` that finds the net quaternion `qnet` corresponding to a rotation by `q1` first and `q2` subsequent to that.

More explicitly, if the quaternion $q_1$ corresponds to a rotation map $R_1$, then for any vector $a$ (which we represent as a pure imaginary quaternion), the rotation takes the form

$$R_1(a) = q_1 a q_1^{-1}$$

And if you have another rotation $R_2$ associated with a quaternion $q_2$, then the whole rotation takes the form

$$R_2 R_1(a) = q_2 q_1 a q_1^{-1} q_2^{-1}$$

So the net quaternion of the rotation is $q_\text{net} = q_2 q_1$.

Still, I consider it a somewhat easy trap to write the multiplication function to switch left and right in this way, convenient though it may be to keep track of which rotation is "first".

Answer (score 2):

That's a complicated test. You should be testing the three multiplications $ij, jk, ki$, which determine everything else. The standard conventions are that these should be $k, i, j$ respectively (the same as the standard convention for the cross product). You can use the opposite convention, that instead we should have $ji, kj, ij$ be equal to $k, i, j$ respectively, but you get the same ring, just with a differently labeled basis of it (more or less).

This is special to the quaternions. In general, if $R$ is a [ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28mathematics%29), there is another ring we can construct from it called its opposite ring $R^{op}$, which has the same addition as $R$ but which has reversed multiplication: that is,

$$a \times^{op} b = b \times a$$

where $\times$ refers to multiplication in $R$ and $\times^{op}$ refers to multiplication in $R^{op}$. If $R$ is commutative then nothing has changed. If $R$ is noncommutative then it can sometimes happen that $R$ and $R^{op}$ are still [isomorphic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism). This is true for the quaternions $\mathbb{H}$, where the isomorphism takes the form

$$\mathbb{H} \ni a + bi + cj + dk \mapsto a - bi - cj - dk \in \mathbb{H}^{op}.$$

However, it is not true in general, not even for [division algebras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algebra).

Comment: This answer made me realize that maybe I should've posted this question in stack overflow and not the math stack exchange :) I think I need to read up more about Quaternions